# Find how many months passed by particular date to now concidering number of days (28,29,30,31)

Tags: php, timestamp

How can we find how many months passed by particular date to current date time, concidering the days per month (ex:-January 31, Feb 28/29 ) using php. 
I tried with
          diff() 
function
not solve my problem. Because it counts how many 30 day months passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it the human way; subtract the months and add one if the day falls before today.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('January 28');

list($old_year, $old_month, $old_day) = explode('-', date('Y-m-d', $timestamp));
list($now_year, $now_month, $now_day) = explode('-', date('Y-m-d'));

$months_ago = 12 * ($now_year - $old_year) + $now_month - $old_month;
if ($old_month < $now_month && $old_day < $now_day) {
    ++$months_ago;
}

echo $months_ago;
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do it :

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-11-15');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-12-15');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%m months'); // output : +1 months
```

You should play around with the DateInterval. It's really powerful.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not accurate. I tried with     $datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-02-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-03-02');                                It returned  0 instead of 1. I think the way that Jack explained is right.

Comment: Cant recommend this solution, a diff from 2020-01-01 to 2020-03-01 returns an interval of 1 month and 29 days. Not as expected 2 months.

Comment: @FabianPicone, that's exactly how it works. The difference should be 2 months. However, if you want to know the involved months, you may want to use

`echo ( intval( $interval->format('%R%m') ) + 1 );`

instead. That would give you `3`